# Attach a remotely stored database

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-connection

Is it possible to attach a database that is stored on a remote server because when I mapped a drive and tried to attach it in management studio, the drive does not show up as an option. I moved it because of disk space and if I cannot what is the alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to attach a database on UNC path (I wouldn't use a mapped drive - that drive is mapped for you, not the SQL Server service account), but you have to ensure that the SQL Server service account has read/write permissions on the remote folder, and you have to run trace flag 1807 ([please read Brent Ozar's post about this](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/01/sql-server-databases-on-network-shares-nas/)).

Also don't use the GUI for this. Once you have the trace flag set, have restarted the service, and have configured permissions correctly, use a new query window, and run the following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name 
ON (Filename = '\\uncpath\share\file.mdf'),
   (Filename = '\\uncpath\share\file.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

(The UI is never going to offer you a UNC path no matter what trace flags you have set or what permissions are enabled.)

Be prepared to handle a corrupted and possibly unrecoverable database should the network share go down, of course.

If that sounds scary to you, good! It should! This is not a good idea at all. Instead you should free up some space, add a drive, or host the database on a different instance.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that. Yes it does not sound like a good idea and I think I will do the attach as a learning step and just to decrease the DB size and recover some stored procedures and then use a local instance. thanks will respond back.