# How to attach my database file .mdf into my local SQL from the LAN network

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mdf

I want to attach my .mdf file into my local sql from the other computer but sql throw the exception:

> Directory lookup for the file
>   "\DATA\SAGOHANO-Server\SQL\SaGoHaNo.mdf" failed with the operating
>   system error 5(Access is denied.).

my code here:

```
CREATE DATABASE SaGoHaNo 
ON (FILENAME = '\\DATA\SAGOHANO-Server\SQL\SaGoHaNo.mdf'), 
(FILENAME = '\\DATA\SAGOHANO-Server\SQL\SaGoHaNo_log.ldf') 
FOR ATTACH;
```

Everyone may help me to fix my issue,please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach a remotely stored database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722551/attach-a-remotely-stored-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message is clear..

The Account under which SQLServer is running doesn't have access to the share in the question..Add the account and give appropriate permissions

Comment: oh.. thank you..Can you give me the way to add the account and appropriate permissions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the complete Server location path like

```
FILENAME = '\\SERVERNAME\DATA\SAGOHANO-Server\SQL\SaGoHaNo.mdf'
```

OR Try

```
FILENAME = '\\SERVERNAME\D$\DATA\SAGOHANO-Server\SQL\SaGoHaNo.mdf'
```

D$ - $ sign after the drive Name

Comment: its LAN network path. I am so sorry because I dont know about servername . Please you can let me know about this?